# multiple selectors with .removeAttr

Tags: jquery, html, css

got following code for a sticky header:

```
    $(function () {
        var navOffset = $(".topnav").offset().top;

        $(window).scroll(function () {
            var scrollPos = $(window).scrollTop();

            if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
                $(".topnav").css({ "position": "fixed", "top": "0", "background-color": "#175e87", "width": "90%", "transition": "all 500ms", "border-bottom": "0px"});
                $(".menu1 li").css({ "color": "#c8c8c8" });
            }
            else {
                $(".topnav").removeAttr('style');
                $(".menu li").removeAttr('style');
            }
        });
```

As you can see i added two css styles  and when the menu becomes fixed again, i want it to remove the stored css for both elements. However it does only remove the first Attr. Thats basically it, i've cheked my selectors, and they seem to be right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From first glance it could be because you add the style to **menu1** li

```
$(".menu1 li").css({ "color": "#c8c8c8" });
```

And then removing it from **menu**

```
$(".menu li").removeAttr('style');
```

They will probably both need to be $("menu1 li")

Comment: oh S#¤!" thank you. im going to delete this question :D